# How do I use the Shooting Star with Factory?

Tags: diep.io

I would like to know how to know how to use the Factory's Shooting Star tactic in Diep.io.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The original guide, [Anokuu's Guide to Master the Master](https://www.reddit.com/r/Diepio/comments/5bwclk/anokuus_guide_to_master_the_master/), was originally posted by [/u/Anokuu](https://www.reddit.com/user/Anokuu) on [/r/Diepio](https://www.reddit.com/r/Diepio/).*

The Shooting Star technique can be used by making all your Factory drones follow your mouse, and keep it in front of you to avoid bullets. This is done to protect yourself from bullets, since the minions can instantly respawn in front of you and can take multiple bullet hits.

In order to trigger the Shooting Star, one must hold shift or right-click continuously and hold their mouse in front of their tank. You must also disable Auto Spin using <kbd>C</kbd>, but having Auto Fire (toggled by <kbd>E</kbd>) is optional.

[image: Auto Fire: ON; Auto Spin: OFF]

If the minions are close enough and within the 'Leash Zone', they will form a Shooting Star.

[image: Shooting Star formed]

With this protection, you can now ram someone, or start using your minions normally. The option that is most effective would depend on your build and your opinion. If you have a build with higher movement speed and body damage, ramming would most likely be more effective.

[/u/Anokuu](https://www.reddit.com/user/Anokuu) describes it this way:

> Use the spinning attract to attract all 6 minions (become a star shape), then charge towards the opponent with the minions as shield in front of the Master. When moving toward a direct along with minions leashed, if you have the same movement speed as bullet speed (For example, 7 bullet speed and 7 movement speed), you don't need to move the mouse because they have the same movement speed as you do.

You can watch a fight against two experienced players, with the first using the Shooting Star tactic and the second using Penta Shot, on YouTube.